# Cabal install current package into its own .cabal-sandbox/*-packages.conf.d

Tags: haskell, cabal

I have a package named `commands`. I want to install it into its own sandbox e.g. `.cabal-sandbox/x86_64-osx-ghc-7.8.3-packages.conf.d/commands-0.0.0-f3f84f48f42ac74a69ee5fd73512bfd0.conf`. currently, there is just one `.hi` interface file for one module `Commands`, I don't know how it got there.

I tried `cabal install commands`, by the logic of "that's how the other packages got there I think", but it fails with unknown package.

I also tried stuff with `ghc-pkg` like `ghc-pkg update commands -f .cabal-sandbox/x86_64-osx-ghc-7.8.3-packages.conf.d` but I'm not using them right. ideally, I'd like to do this with cabal.

the last thing I tried was `ghc -idist/build/`, but it complained about the package names in the interface files being different, command versus main ("... differs from name found in the interface file ..."). and if I faked the executable's package with `ghc -package-name commands-0.0.0`, the linker complained that it couldn't find the symbol `_ZCMain_main_closure`, because every executable needs the function `main` in the module `Main` in the package `main`.

I'm sure there's a better way of doing this.

I followed online examples for my cabal file:

```
$ cat commands.cabal
name: commands
library
exposed-modules: Commands.Types, Commands.Bits
...
```

the minimal failing code example is just:

```
$ cat Main.hs
import Commands.Types
main = return ()
```

in the root project directory.

Context: I need to build my executable with `make` (not `cabal`) because it links to foreign code (Objective-C via language-c-inline). my makefile: https://github.com/sboosali/Haskell-DragonNaturallySpeaking/blob/master/Makefile). thus, I have to compile a script explicitly. I don't know how to compile the `executable` with cabal, but I want cabal to build and test and manage my `library`.

By putting my package into the sandbox, I will be able to import its modules from the script, by compiling with `cabal exec -- ghc`. I will also be able to include the script with `extra-source-files` at least, and know it will work.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I'd try:

1. First unregister any previous commands library. Try 
   `ghc-pkg --global unregister commands`
2. Install new commands to your sandbox.
   From your sandbox directory, try this:
   `cabal --enable-shared --disable-documentation --prefix=./ install /path/to/your/library/source`

Note the prefix specification.

Comment: can you explain what the first and third options do?

Comment: --prefix=./ failed to run on cabal-install 1.22.6.0.1 (cabal library 1.22.4.0, ghc 7.8.3). The command worked with --prefix= ommitted, though.

Answer (score 0):

I nuked it (`rm -fr .cabal-sandbox/`), reinstalled everything (`cabal install --only-dependencies`), added itself as a source (`cabal sandbox add-source .`),  installed it (`cabal install command`). and then `make` worked. idk...